# how should we place marker on google maps in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

How should we place marker on google maps, with which am getting latitude & longitude from server?

And i'll be updating that latitude & longitude for every 5 seconds. so, The marker should move it's position.

How to achieve this? without refreshing google maps?

Comment: There is already lots of answer available pls first check them.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is for adding marker to google map

```
func designGoogleMapAndSetTheMarker(withLattitude lattitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
  camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 16)
  googleMapView.camera = camera
  marker = GMSMarker()
  marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lattitude, longitude)
  marker.map = googleMapView
```

> When ever you need to update the marker need to add below code

```
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lattitude, longitude)
```